# Datatable refreshes to first page

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I have been doing a particular operation on a datatable. While completing a Ajax is being called, on the success of which `fnDraw()` is being called and it refreshes the datatable going directly to the starting page of the Datatable. It makes a bad user experience as the user has to again go to the particular page where he/she has performed the operation. I have tried various ways but it seems the only way may be to alter the default `datatables.js`.

Please help on how to solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried ajax.reload() with resetPaging as false?

Answer (score 2):

For **jQuery DataTables 1.9**, use [`fnStandingRedraw`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnStandingRedraw) plugin.

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnStandingRedraw = function(oSettings) {
    if(oSettings.oFeatures.bServerSide === false){
        var before = oSettings._iDisplayStart;

        oSettings.oApi._fnReDraw(oSettings);

        // iDisplayStart has been reset to zero - so lets change it back
        oSettings._iDisplayStart = before;
        oSettings.oApi._fnCalculateEnd(oSettings);
    }

    // draw the 'current' page
    oSettings.oApi._fnDraw(oSettings);
};


$(document).ready(function() {
      var table = $('#example').dataTable()
      table.fnStandingRedraw();
  } );
```

For **jQuery DataTables 1.10+**, just call [`draw(false)`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) to avoid resetting the page.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable()

/* ... */

table.draw(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> `table.fnPageChange(3,true);`

Where 3 is the page number and the second parameter asks datatable to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it worked for me.

```
var table = $("#dataTable").DataTable({
  stateSave : true,
  ...
});
```