# R shiny DT table with pagination and drop down list inside table and being able to save the entire updated table as csv file

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have been experimenting with R shiny DT table with pagination and drop down list inside table and being able to save the entire updated table as csv file.The probelm I am encountering is when I click into other pages other than the first page and select a choice from any drop down list, it always goes back to first page. Much appreciated if anyone can help me out for this!

```
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
library(DT)

# Define the choices for the drop down menu
# choices <- c("A", "B", "C")

# Define the data table with a column that has drop down menu
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/jyang29/Downloads/saved_data.csv")
# data$Choice <- sapply(data$Species, function(x) {
#   as.character(selectInput(paste0("choice_", x), "", choices, selected = x))
# })


ui <- fluidPage(
  div(id = "dropdown-container"),
  DTOutput("myDataTable"),
  actionButton('update', 'Refresh Table'),
  actionButton("saveBtn", "Save as CSV"),
  # tags$script(src = "www/custom.js")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Reactive values to store the data
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = data)
  # Render the DataTable
  output$myDataTable <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      rv$data,
      editable = TRUE,
      escape = FALSE,
      selection = 'none',
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(list(
          targets = 5,
          render = JS(
            "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
            "  if (type === 'display') {",
            "    var dropdownValue = data;",
            "    var rowIndex = meta.row;",
            "    return '<select class=\"dropdown\" data-row=\"' + rowIndex + '\"><option value=\"setosa\"' + (dropdownValue === 'setosa' ? ' selected' : '') + '>setosa</option><option value=\"versicolor\"' + (dropdownValue === 'versicolor' ? ' selected' : '') + '>versicolor</option><option value=\"virginica\"' + (dropdownValue === 'virginica' ? ' selected' : '') + '>virginica</option></select>';",
            "  }",
            "  return data;",
            "}"
          )
        )),
        # Use JavaScript to make the drop down menu work
        preDrawCallback = JS(
          "function() {",
          "  Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());",
          "}"
        ),
        drawCallback = JS(
          "function() {",
          "  Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());",
          "}"
        ),
        initComplete = JS(
          "function(settings, json) {",
          # "  var table = settings.oInstance.api();",
          # "  table.column(5).data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {",
          # "    $('.dropdown').eq(j).val(d);",
          # "  });",
          "  $('.dropdown').on('mousedown', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });",
          # "  var proxy = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);",
          
          "  var api = this.api();",
          # "    $('#pageLength').change(function() {",
          # "      api.page.len($(this).val()).draw();",
          # "      pageInfo.pageLength = $(this).val();",
          # "    });",
          # "    api.on('draw.dt', function() {",
          # "      currentPage = api.page()+1;",
          # "      pageLength = api.page.len();",
          # "      console.log('Current Page:', currentPage);",
          # "      console.log('Page Length:', pageLength);",
          # "    });",
          # "    console.log(api);",
          
          "  $('.dataTables_length select').on('change', function() {",
          "    console.log('RRR');",
          "    currentPage = api.page()+1;",
          "    pageLength = api.page.len();",
          "    console.log('Current Page:', currentPage);",
          "    console.log('Page Length:', pageLength);",
          "  });",
          
          
          "  $('#myDataTable').on('change', '.dropdown', function() {",
          # "    $ ('[class=\"dropdown\"]').on ('change', function () {",
          "    var selectedValue = $(this).val();",
          "    var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();",
          
          # "    var table = $().dataTables();",
          # "    table.draw(false);",  #Check these 2 lines of code!!
          
          # "    var currentPage = dataTable.page() + 1;",
          # "    var pageLength = dataTable.page.len();",
          "      currentPage = api.page()+1;",
          "      pageLength = api.page.len();",
          "      console.log('Current Page:', currentPage);",
          "      console.log('Page Length:', pageLength);",
          "      console.log(rowIndex);",
          "      console.log(selectedValue);",
         
          
          # "    var currentPage = table.page();", # Get current page number
          # "    console.log(proxy);",
          # "    console.log(table);",
          #"    var pageLength = table.page.info().length;", # Get page length
          "    Shiny.setInputValue('myDataTable_cell_edit', {",
          "      row: rowIndex+1+(currentPage-1)*pageLength,",
          "      col: 5,",
          "      value: selectedValue",
          #"      currentPage: currentPage + 1,",
          #"      pageLength: pageLength",
          "    }, {priority: 'event'});",
          "  });",
          "}"
        ),
        
        buttons = 
          list('copy', 'print', list(
            extend = 'collection',
            buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
            text = 'Download'
          ))
      ),
      
      # callback = JS(
      #   "table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {",
      #   "  var $this = $(this.node());",
      #   "  $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);",
      #   "  $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');",
      #   "});",
      #   "Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());",
      #   "Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());"
      # )
    )
  }, server = TRUE
  )
  
  # Observe changes to the DataTable and update reactiveValues accordingly
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('myDataTable')
  
  # observeEvent(input$myDataTable_cell_edit, {
  #   info <- input$myDataTable_cell_edit
  #   str(info)
  #   rv$data[info$row, info$col] <<- info$value
  #   print(head(rv$data, 12))
  # })
  
  observeEvent(input$myDataTable_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$myDataTable_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    k = info$value
    print(i)
    print(j)
    print(k)

    # isolate(
    #   for (m in 1:length(info$row)) {
    #     print(i[m])
    #     print(j[m])
    #     print(k[m])
    #     rv$data[i[m], j[m]] <<- DT::coerceValue(k[m], rv$data[i[m], j[m]])
    #   }
    # )

    isolate({
      rv$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(k, rv$data[i, j])

    })
    rv$data <<- editData(rv$data, info)
    replaceData(proxy, rv$data, resetPaging = FALSE)
    print(head(rv$data))
    
    # If the edited cell is in the Choice column, update the drop down menu
    # if (j == 6) {
    #   # rv$data[i, j] <<- as.character(selectInput(
    #   #   paste0("choice_", k), "", choices, selected = k
    #   # ))
    #   rv$data[i, j] <<- coerceValue(k, rv$data[i, j])
    # } else {
    #   # Otherwise, update the cell value
    #   rv$data[i, j] <<- coerceValue(k, rv$data[i, j])
    # }
  })
  
  
  # Event reactive to update the data based on the selection
  df <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    # tibble(Column1 = c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3"), Column2 = as.character(input$selection1))
    input$myDataTable_cell_edit$data
  })
  
  # Observe changes in the event reactive and update reactiveValues
  observe({
    rv$data <- df()
  })
  # Save the data as CSV
  observeEvent(input$saveBtn, {
    print(input)
    write.csv(rv$data, "C:/Users/jyang29/Downloads/saved_data.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651201/datatable-refreshes-to-first-page , and updated my code accordingly, it still does not work.

Comment: Try to replace `datatable(rv$data, ...)` with `datatable(isolate(rv$data), ...`.